# How can I route 401 and 403 errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this in my startup:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
routes.MapRoute(
    "404-PageNotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" }
    );
});
```

It redirects 404 errors to the Error page as expected.  How can I do this with a 401 and/or 403 error? I have tried this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "401",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Error" }
        );
});
```

I have spent hours Googling this today and have found nothing.  Some other answers talk about creating handlers like this: [Override AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.Net Core and respond Json status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637504/override-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core-and-respond-json-status?rq=1).  However, I believe it is an overkill for me.

How can I route 401 or 403 errors?

If it makes any difference; it is a Web API .NET Core 2.1 returning the 401 / 403 error and an MVC Core MVC 2.1 app handling the error.

Comment: Is web.config an option? https://serverfault.com/questions/699805/how-can-i-redirect-http-iis7-response-403-forbidden-to-https

Answer (score 2):

Configure status code pages
By default, an app doesn't provide a rich status code page for HTTP status codes, such as 404 Not Found. To provide status code pages, use Status Code Pages Middleware.

The middleware is made available by the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics` package, which is available in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage.

Add a line to the Startup.Configure method:

[image]

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
        "Status code page, status code: " + 
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
});
```

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1) here for the related documentation