# .NET Core 3.1 Adding security to my intranet REST endpoint, authenticate against windows service account/Active Directory

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, active-directory, windows-authentication

I used the first answer in this post to utilize the Policy strategy: [Override AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.Net Core and respond Json status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637504/override-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core-and-respond-json-status)

I have been working on this for a couple of days and cannot figure out the correct solution.  When I add the authorize and add my Active Directory group and through the web client Swagger endpoint, it authenticates me perfectly fine.  But I am trying to include permissions for a Windows Service (WCF app) that uses HTTP client to call my new REST endpoint.  It will not identify the service account as the user making the REST call.  Is there something I need to add ot my HttpClient object to get it to pass the Service Account identity?  Or any other ideas?

There are groups at my company that I do not want to have access to my new REST Service, but some older code still needs to have the permission to call the new Endpoint (this endpoint used to also be WCF).

Answer (score 0):

try to add the endpoint http by using netsh on admin cmd,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http

Examples

Following are three examples of the show urlacl command.

```
add urlacl url=https://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN/USER
add urlacl url=https://www.contoso.com:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN/USER
show urlacl
```

you can also just use 'everyone' instead of 'domain/user'

see if this works for you. or might be something different.

Comment: So are you saying I would add each user group or service account manually through this?  This feels strange that you would need to bound your security permissions outside of your codebase or configuration.  Does this mean I should remove the authorize attributes from my code base?

Comment: you know by using WCF this is the way to bind your http WCF Service. Also you can add an iplisten to bind your external ip
From microsoft.
ipaddress The IPv4 or IPv6 address to be added to the IP listen list. The IP listen list is used to scope the list of addresses to which the HTTP service binds. "0.0.0.0" means any IPv4 address and "::" means any IPv6 address.

you can add directly the port instead of the service just by using +:Port instead of +:Port/yourWCFInterface